# g8 does not understand docker cli syntax

Tags: scala, docker, giter8

I have a customized g8 scala template which contains a `.travis.yml` that can be used by projects created though this template. In my `.travis.yml`, I have `docker login -u="$username" -p="$password"` because I need to publish images to remote registry. However, when I try to create a boilerplate project by doing `g8 file://template.g8`, I always get this error `.travis.yml, 31:42: '" -p="' came as a complete surprise to me.`
 I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Need to escape all the `$`s.